# Is 1080Ti good for mining ETH?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, rig

Hi guys I am thinking of buying some serious rig for mining. Since AMD GPUs are out of stocks, I am thinking to buy 1080Ti. The problem is that I can't find any comparison of hashrate for this card and other 'high end' GPUs from AMD... My second question is: What about Titan X GPU? I am planning to invest about 5k in USD for this rig.

Comment: Hi there. I think your question will probably be closed as off-topic, I'm afraid. It's asking for a recommendation, rather than posing a specific, answerable question, and this board isn't the best fit for that type of thing. www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/ would be better :-)

Comment: Debating the pros and cons of particular products is considered off topic on Stack Exchange, because it invites spam.  In addition to reddit, you might try the Ethereum Forum: https://forum.ethereum.org

Answer (score 1):

Not any better than GTX1070. It's because it's 1080 is DDR5X, different processing speed or something iirc.

I'd suggest getting a GTX1070 for price/MHs.

I last heard 1080 gets 25-27MH/s overclocked. While GTX1070 can go above 31MH/s.

I mine at 29.5MH/s with Claymore miner. Using it for personal PC as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm. Then also 1080Ti will be any better... is there some specific edition for 1070 to look for? Or it is not important?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed 1080TI and 1080. Apparently 1080TI is slightly better than 1070. You can check out this guy post.

http://1stminingrig.com/best-mining-rig-hardware-mine-2017/#GPU_GTX_1060_1070_1080_series